# PayPal Express Checkout button with validation on onClick

Tags: javascript, validation, paypal

I'm trying to add validation to an old integration that uses the PayPal button version **2.1.102**
The integration supports validation on button render, but not on `onClick()` function.
I have change the validation and `onClick()` methods so that I have the actions in the `onClick()`, but once enabled the validation is ignored.
...

```js
onClick: function(e) {
   var isValid = $('#billing-form').validate().form();
   if (!isValid) {
      paypalActions.disable();
   } else {
      paypalActions.enable();
   }
},
validate: function(actions) {
   actions.disable(); 
   paypalActions = actions;
}
```

And the button is rendered with this script:

```js
paypal.Button.render(configCYP,'#paypal-button-container');
```

where configCYP contains all the configurations + the `onClick()` and validate methods.

I saw that newer version have the options to restrict and resolve in the actions, but in this version I only have enable and disable.

Has anyone manage to make the validation work `onClick()` ?